# String on multiple lines in C

Tags: c, string

when the input looks like this(on several lines):

```
good morning 
my friends
whats up
```

how does `fgets` read it? I mean is `\0` character at the end of each line or is it on the last line only?

I mean: is it like this:

```
good morning\0\n
my friends\0\n
whats up\0
```

or is it like this:

```
good morning\n
my friends\n
whats up\0
```

I am just wondering.

Comment: Neither: it's `good morning\n\0` for each line.

Comment: Oh, I see! thank you

Comment: And if the last line of the file does not contain a `\n`, the last line read won't contain a `\n` either. Read the documentation, it's all written there.

Comment: Also note that it highly depends on how many byes you read. If you onyl read 4 byte per `fgets` call. The first call will return `good\0`.

Comment: yes, I understand. Thank you very much. I am just trying to figure out one problem and how to solve it and this helped a lot

Comment: Be very careful here: in Linux you have #13 at the end of every line. In Windows you have a combination of #13 and #10.

Comment: @Dominique In Linux it is #10 (LF) not #13 (CR), and fgets() eliminates the #13 in Windows when parsing the string, you don't need to worry about it. It is a portable function after all.

Comment: @Ackdari If you call `fgets(s, 4, file);` you will get `goo\0`, because `fgets()` is only allowed to write 4 bytes. the last `d` will be read by the next read operation.